# Entity Framework is trying to create a database, but its not what I want

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have a small asp.net mvc4 application (working fine in my local machine), that uses entity framework v4.1.0.0 with ADO.net DbContext Generator.(SQL Server 2008 r2)

I am adding newer versions of dlls required through the "Add Deployable Dependencies..." context menu in Visual Studio 2010.

I have a shared hosting with godaddy.com, I have uploaded the files to server and created the database, now here comes the problem.When I try to browse my site I get the following error:

**CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.**

I looked this up around and found out that this error was caused by EF code first trying to create database.**but i do not want EF code first to recreate the database, how do i turn off this automatic database creation altogether?** I have no intentions of using the code-first feature whatsoever.

Please help.

Answer (score 24):

put this code into the Application_Start() method of Global.asax or constructor on your DbContext class

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

If you want to recreate database when POCO domains are changed, use following code instead of above

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());
```

Comment: I tried putting `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);` in both the global.asax and the constructor, it isnt working, am i missing something?

Comment: Check out connection string in your web application. I doubt that the database EF try to create is different from the database you created  already.

Comment: What I failed mention in the question was I was also following [this Hanselman post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) about universal providers, which, as I found out after closely inspecting the stack trace, also tried to create a database for aspnet membership and profiles. So then I reverted back to older aspnet membership and provider setting in the web.config now, and now it works, thank you for the effort @Ray

Comment: It worked. I had to write Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null); for every the model.

Comment: 6 years later, and this worked for my MVC 4 Entity Framework 6 project on a hosted server. Legend!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EF Migrations, this is what you set for it:

```
public sealed class DbConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DatabaseContext>
{
    public DbConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't answer the question on EF Code First itself. If the database already exists, then EF will not try to create it. So you just need to point it to an existing database. And to make sure the connection string name is the same as the name of the database context. If it is not, you need to provide it to it with some overrides:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext() 
      : base(ApplicationParameters.ConnectionStringName)
    {
    }

    public DatabaseContext(string connectionStringName)
      : base(connectionStringName)
    {
    }

}
```