# Entity Framework 6 - SqlConnection Open() works but EF tries to Create Database again - External Hosting

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-hosting

I have an ASP.NET MVC 6 web application (with WebApi) installed on an external server hosted by 1&1.co.uk (limited access tools). The server is running Windows Server 2016 Standard and SQL Server 2017 RTM.

I created the database from their `myLittleAdmin` tool and created the tables using the SQL output from EF `Update-Database -Verbose`. The tables seem fine.

The error generated whenever Entity Framework invokes the DbContext is

> FAILED: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

which implies that EF is trying to create a fresh database, when the database is already there and my connection string works in a `SqlConnection` instance.

The weird thing that I'd like help with is that I have tested the connection string in a `SqlConnection` instance that connects OK to the database without crashing.

**Question**: how does Entity Framework and the `DbContext` differ from a `SqlConnection`? And what can I do to get Entity Framework to use the existing database?

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
     try
     {
         conn.Open();
         message = "Connection opened."; // THIS WORKS!
         conn.Dispose();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         message = $"FAILED: { e.Message}\n{e.StackTrace}\n{e.Source}, Connection String: {connStr}";
     }
}
```

I call this function through a test controller that I've setup on the server which returns the message to the View through the ViewBag. But any function that tries to call EF bombs out with the above error.

The truly maddening thing is that I could register new users on the server a few weeks back but I needed to nuke the database because my Entity Ids were setup as int instead of strings. And now this.

Note: AFAIK I don't have Remote Desktop access to the server, IIS or SQL Manager terminals, just the noddy myLittleAdmin terminal where I can run SQL queries. Oh and a telephone to an unhelpful support desk.

Full Stacktrace available in the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Found [this answer by Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598715/entity-framework-is-trying-to-create-a-database-but-its-not-what-i-want), a one line wonder!

In the Application_Start() method of Global.asax, add:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
    ...
}
```

Here's the documentation explanation:

```
// Summary:
//     Sets the database initializer to use for the given context type. The database
//     initializer is called when a the given System.Data.Entity.DbContext type is used
//     to access a database for the first time. The default strategy for Code First
//     contexts is an instance of System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.
//
// Parameters:
//   strategy:
//     The initializer to use, or null to disable initialization for the given context
//     type.
```